# Json converted from XML not parsing with Model

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am calling an XML format API and converting it to Json to use it within a Flutter mobile app

I am using xml2Json and it is converting fine

As seen below I call `print(jsonMap);` and it displays the correct `Json` data in `GData` format

I then take my Json parse model, built with Quicktype.io off of the Json model and call `locations = Locations.fromJson(jsonMap);` as seen below to allow to to draw the required data out. I am currently then just calling `print(locations);` to check whether its working and the data is returning before implementing the parsed data into the app fully.

I have tried shuffling round everything, I've adapted the Model several times and tried all kinds of methods to parse the data.

I am calling other APIs with the exact same method successfully and the code method is identical in this one. The only difference is the `xml2Json` convert, which is converting fine (`JsonMap` printing converted XML correctly), so I'm struggling the see what should be different.

Thanks for reading

**The call**

```
Future<Locations> fetchLiveLocations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var locations;
    Xml2Json xml2Json = new Xml2Json(); 

    
 try{
    var response = await client.get('API_CALL');    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    xml2Json.parse(response.body);
    var jsonString = xml2Json.toGData();
    var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    print(jsonMap);

    locations = Locations.fromJson(jsonMap);
    print(locations);

  }
 } catch(Exception) {
  return locations;
 }

  return locations;
 }
```

**Model**

```
import 'dart:convert';

Locations locationsFromJson(String str) => Locations.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String locationsToJson(Locations data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Locations {
    Locations({
        this.vehicleActivity,
    });

    List<VehicleActivity> vehicleActivity;

    factory Locations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Locations(
        vehicleActivity: List<VehicleActivity>.from(json["VehicleActivity"].map((x) => VehicleActivity.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "VehicleActivity": List<dynamic>.from(vehicleActivity.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class VehicleActivity {
    VehicleActivity({
        this.recordedAtTime,
        this.itemIdentifier,
        this.validUntilTime,
        this.monitoredVehicleJourney,
        this.extensions,
    });

    DateTime recordedAtTime;
    String itemIdentifier;
    DateTime validUntilTime;
    MonitoredVehicleJourney monitoredVehicleJourney;
    Extensions extensions;

    factory VehicleActivity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VehicleActivity(
        recordedAtTime: DateTime.parse(json["RecordedAtTime"]),
        itemIdentifier: json["ItemIdentifier"],
        validUntilTime: DateTime.parse(json["ValidUntilTime"]),
        monitoredVehicleJourney: MonitoredVehicleJourney.fromJson(json["MonitoredVehicleJourney"]),
        extensions: Extensions.fromJson(json["Extensions"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "RecordedAtTime": recordedAtTime.toIso8601String(),
        "ItemIdentifier": itemIdentifier,
        "ValidUntilTime": validUntilTime.toIso8601String(),
        "MonitoredVehicleJourney": monitoredVehicleJourney.toJson(),
        "Extensions": extensions.toJson(),
    };
}

class Extensions {
    Extensions({
        this.vehicleJourney,
    });

    VehicleJourney vehicleJourney;

    factory Extensions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Extensions(
        vehicleJourney: VehicleJourney.fromJson(json["VehicleJourney"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "VehicleJourney": vehicleJourney.toJson(),
    };
}

class VehicleJourney {
    VehicleJourney({
        this.operational,
        this.vehicleUniqueId,
        this.driverRef,
    });

    Operational operational;
    int vehicleUniqueId;
    int driverRef;

    factory VehicleJourney.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VehicleJourney(
        operational: Operational.fromJson(json["Operational"]),
        vehicleUniqueId: json["VehicleUniqueId"],
        driverRef: json["DriverRef"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Operational": operational.toJson(),
        "VehicleUniqueId": vehicleUniqueId,
        "DriverRef": driverRef,
    };
}

class Operational {
    Operational({
        this.ticketMachine,
    });

    TicketMachine ticketMachine;

    factory Operational.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Operational(
        ticketMachine: TicketMachine.fromJson(json["TicketMachine"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TicketMachine": ticketMachine.toJson(),
    };
}

class TicketMachine {
    TicketMachine({
        this.ticketMachineServiceCode,
        this.journeyCode,
    });

    dynamic ticketMachineServiceCode;
    int journeyCode;

    factory TicketMachine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TicketMachine(
        ticketMachineServiceCode: json["TicketMachineServiceCode"],
        journeyCode: json["JourneyCode"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TicketMachineServiceCode": ticketMachineServiceCode,
        "JourneyCode": journeyCode,
    };
}

class MonitoredVehicleJourney {
    MonitoredVehicleJourney({
        this.lineRef,
        this.directionRef,
        this.publishedLineName,
        this.operatorRef,
        this.destinationRef,
        this.vehicleLocation,
        this.blockRef,
        this.vehicleJourneyRef,
        this.vehicleRef,
    });

    int lineRef;
    String directionRef;
    int publishedLineName;
    String operatorRef;
    int destinationRef;
    VehicleLocation vehicleLocation;
    int blockRef;
    String vehicleJourneyRef;
    int vehicleRef;

    factory MonitoredVehicleJourney.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MonitoredVehicleJourney(
        lineRef: json["LineRef"],
        directionRef: json["DirectionRef"],
        publishedLineName: json["PublishedLineName"],
        operatorRef: json["OperatorRef"],
        destinationRef: json["DestinationRef"],
        vehicleLocation: VehicleLocation.fromJson(json["VehicleLocation"]),
        blockRef: json["BlockRef"],
        vehicleJourneyRef: json["VehicleJourneyRef"],
        vehicleRef: json["VehicleRef"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "LineRef": lineRef,
        "DirectionRef": directionRef,
        "PublishedLineName": publishedLineName,
        "OperatorRef": operatorRef,
        "DestinationRef": destinationRef,
        "VehicleLocation": vehicleLocation.toJson(),
        "BlockRef": blockRef,
        "VehicleJourneyRef": vehicleJourneyRef,
        "VehicleRef": vehicleRef,
    };
}

class VehicleLocation {
    VehicleLocation({
        this.longitude,
        this.latitude,
    });

    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    factory VehicleLocation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VehicleLocation(
        longitude: json["Longitude"].toDouble(),
        latitude: json["Latitude"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Longitude": longitude,
        "Latitude": latitude,
    };
}
```

Response when I request specific data from the model

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'vehicleActivity' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

Comment: Can you add response example to your question?

Comment: @fartem Thanks for your response, when I ```print``` there is no response at all. But when I request specific data from the ```call``` it responds as ```null```, I will post full response above at bottom of question. Thanks